# sql command line- export into dynamic file name

Tags: mysql

```
mysql --host *HOST* --p   --user *USERNAME*  -e "query"  > file.lst
pause
```

my code looks as above. Is there a way to rename the `file.lst` and add `sysdate` at the end and make it like : `file12072016.lst`? Assume that the date needs to be changed everyday and the file is run everyday

Comment: Are you using **linux**?

Comment: no windows, i'm using command line, the codes are fine, just having problem with the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
mysql --host *HOST* --p   --user *USERNAME*  -e "query"  > "file_name__%date:/=%_%time:~0
,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.lst"
```

The name of the generated file will be like this:

`file_name__Tue 07122016_13-31-15.lst`

**EDIT:**

The following command will generate file name as follows:

**`file_name_12072016.lst`**

```
mysql --host *HOST* --p   --user *USERNAME*  -e "query"  > "file_name_%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~10,4%.lst"
```

Comment: thank you. edited the answer a bit to match my requirements. it worked fine